# Calculate P(A ∪ B) if it is given that P(A) = 1/3 and P(B | Ac) = 1/4.

Tags: probability, statistics

"Calculate P(A ∪ B) if it is given that P(A) = 1/3 and P(B | Ac) = 1/4."

The textbook solution is 1/2 although I can't seem to get there. Here's what I have so far...

P(Ac) = 2/3

P(A) = (2/3)c = 1/3

P(B | Ac) = P(B ∩ Ac) / P(Ac)

¼ = P(B ∩ Ac) / 2/3

P(B ∩ Ac) = 1/6

P(B ∩ Ac) = P(B) + P(Ac) – P(B ∪ Ac)

1/6 = P(B) + (2/3) – P(B ∪ Ac)?

Thanks!

Comment: What does Ac mean?

Comment: @saulspatz: I think it must mean $A^c$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  $A$ and $B\cap A^c$ are disjoint and their union is $A\cup B$ (draw a Venn diagram if you need to convince yourself).

So $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B\cap A^c)=\frac13+\frac16 = \frac12$.